# Term Stores and sharepoint online/on premise

Tags: sharepoint-online, term-store, sharepoint-on-prem

Just wondering why its not possible to create global terms for SharePoint that span across site collections. Is it because they are meant not to be used in this way?
If this is the case then should one site collection be created with its sole purpose to hold global terms and then shared out to other site collections?

Thanks

Comment: It just isn't there (yet?). It would sure be nice to have a hybrid managed metadata service like hybrid search. Maybe toss it out there as an option in the SharePoint user voice? https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/

Comment: How about write a feature publish it whenever you create a Site Collection?